# Thread pooling and multi core systems

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, threadpool, multicore

Do you think threadpooling design pattern is the way to go for the multi-core future?

A threadpooling library for instance, if used extensively, makes/force the application writer

(1) to break the problem into separate parallel jobs hence promoting (enforcing :) ) parallelism

(2) With abstraction from all the low level OS calls, synchronization etc etc makes programmer's life easier. (Especially for C programmers :) )

I have strong belief its the best way (Or One of the "best" ways :) ) for multi-core future...

So, my question is, am I write in thinking so or I am in some delusion :)

Regards,

Microkernel

Comment: This question is somewhat unclear. A guideline on SO is that each question should have a definitive correct answer (once found, if ever). I'd suggest making this Community Wiki, as it is an interesting topic, but as much as a question, it is a discussion topic.

Comment: Hmm, yeah community wiki makes more sense to me as well Anders... Doing it :)

Comment: Oops, how do I make this post community wiki!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thread pooling is a technique that involves a queue and a number of threads taking jobs from the queue and process them. This is in contrast to the technique of just starting new threads whenever a new task arrives.

Benefits are that the maximum number of threads is *limited* to avoid *too much threading* and that there is less overhead involved with any new task (Thread is already running and takes task. No threat starting needed).

Whether this is a good design highly depends on your problem. If you have many short jobs that come to your program at a very fast rate, then this is a good idea because the lower overhead is really a benefit. If you have extremely large numbers of concurrent tasks this is a good idea to keep your scheduler from having to do too much work.

There are many areas where thread pooling is just not helpful. So you cannot generalize. Sometimes multi threading at all is not possible. Or not even desired, as multi threading adds an unpredictable element (race conditions) to your code which is extremely hard to debug.

A thread pooling library can hardly "force" you to use it. You still need to think stuff through and if you just start one thread... Won't help.

Answer (score 1):

As almost every informatics topic the answer is: It Depends.

the pooling system is fine with Embarrassingly parallel http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel

For other task where you need more syncornization between threads it's not that good

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows NT engine thread pools are usually much less efficient than I/O Completion Ports. These are covered extensively in numerous questions and answers here. IOCPs enable event-driven processing in that multiple threads can wait on the IOCP until an event occurs due to an IOC (read or write) on a socket or handle which is then queued to the IOCP. The IOCP in turn pairs a waiting thread with the id of the event and releases the thread for processing. After the thread has processed the event and initiated a new I/O it returns to the IOCP to wait for the next event (which may or may not be the completion of the I/O it just initiated).

IOCs may also be artificially signalled by explicit posting from a non-event.

Using IOCPs is not polling. The optimal IOCP implementation will have as many threads waiting on the IOCP as there are cores in the system. The threads may all execute the same physical code if that is deemed efficient. Since a thread processes from an IOC up until it issues an I/O it does nothing which forces it to wait for other resources except perhaps to compete for access to thread-safe areas. It is a natural choice to move away from the "one handle per thread" paradigm. IOCP-controlled threads are therefore as efficient as the programmer is able to construct them.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by @yaankee a lot except I would argue that thread pool is almost always the right way to go. The reason: a thread pool can degenerate itself into a simple static work partitioning model for problems like matrix-matrix multiply. OpenMP guided is kind of along those lines.